# Regex POSIX and excluding characters

Tags: regex, grep, posix

I have a question concerning POSIX regular expressions. I use SVN, where it annoys me much, when I call `svn st` just to see interesting information drown in a flood of externals:

```
$ svn st
X       Application/something/somewhere
X       Application/something/other_place
    X   Application/something/OTHERPALCE
    X   Application/something/yetANOTHERplace
X       Application/something/SOMEWHERE
...
```

So I devised a regex to filter this mess and wrote `svn st | grep "^[^X]{5}"`, but this filters also other, useful information out, whereas `svn st | grep "^[^X]...[^X]"` for example works fine. Why?

Comment: you could use `awk {'print $3'}`

Comment: To make it clear: these are the lines you want to skip, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your grep line has two problems:

- for '{m,n}', you need `grep -E` or `grep '^[^X]\{m\}`
- it should be `^[^X]{4}`, not `{5}`. because the fifth char is `X`, and your `grep "^[^X]...[^X]"` should not "work fine". or you have different example. here it outputs nothing.

Comment: It worked. Only in the point 2 you misunderstood me, because all the lines above should be filetered out - those with "X" on the right side too. Thank you very much anyway. :)

Comment: @Sventimir oh, I think i misunderstood  your requirement.... I thought you want the two lines in output.... anyway, you need escape or `-E`

Comment: I assume I wrote it ambigiously. Sorry for that.